# How to temporarily cover holes in exterior walls while awaiting new siding installation?

Tags: sealing, siding, aluminum

The second floor of my house uses crumbling tar covered OSB for sheathing, with no house wrap. This sheathing has multiple holes / gaps / large breaks, and is allowing moisture, bugs, and exterior air to infiltrate the interior walls / fiberglass in the walls. This ends up smelling bad, and people who sleep in affected rooms have respiratory issues the next day.

In the nursery, I went nuts and [sealed it from the inside](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/247230/how-to-temporarily-cover-holes-in-exterior-wall) - I covered the holes with self adhesive window flashing, put insulation back in, then redid the drywall - and while the wall isn't quite finished, the air quality is dramatically improved in there.

Now I am having big problems in a second room (next to the first). The real solution is new siding, sheathing, and house wrap - I am working on scheduling that, but it's still 6-12 weeks out.

I was thinking about trying to tackle the problems in this room from the exterior (because removing and reinstalling all that drywall is a lot of work). In other words, I'm considering removing the aluminum siding and sealing the holes that way. It's probably going to be too cold now to use the self adhesive flashing to seal the holes, so I could perhaps staple house wrap to the whole area.

The area in question is above this porch. I am thinking about removing the siding between the red lines.

What would be the right way to (temporarily) weather seal this area if I do so? I was imagining putting house wrap over it (excluding the window) and then screwing in 2x2's around the edge of the house wrap to secure it. It's probably too cold to use the self adhesive window flashing, so what do I do around the window? More 2x2s to secure the house wrap?

Is there a better way?

(Ignore the raised flashing above the porch - that was me, so I could get my camera in there to verify that the problem is indeed crumbled/broken sheathing).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Housewrap the whole area, including the window, and then cut the window opening in the housewrap as housewrap window openings are usually cut (don't cut a rectangle, cut in to the center from the corners and fold flaps back underneath to expose the window before securing the wrap.)

2x2 is overkill if you can find cedar lath in your area (roughly 1/4-3/8 x 1.25 x 48 inch wooden strips. Sold in a bundle.) Or you could rip a 2x2 into about 4 pieces, or rip strips from 1/4" plywood.

The "bad smells" bit makes me doubt the wisdom of replacing the (same) fiberglass into the wall - unless the air outside smells bad, that sounds like something rotting or molding in the wall, and fiberglass is prone to being a haven for nastiness when things get wet.